# How to annotate at specific points in a scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Having this data:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,  4,  9,  3,  1,  6,  5, 10,  8,  7),
                 var2 = c(1,  4,  7, 10,  9,  2,  8,  3,  5,  6),
                 var3 = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)),
                 var4 = letters[1:10])
```

and ploting var1 and var2 by var3

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=var1, y=var2,
                      shape = var3,
                      color = var3)) + geom_point(size=4)
```

I would like to highlight specific points by adding the corresponding character in var4, for example:

- annotate at `df[4,1:2]` the corresponding value in var4 (`df[4,4]`)
- annotate at `df[3,1:2]` the corresponding value in var4 (`df[3,4]`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would be ok for start?

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=var1, y=var2, shape = var3, color = var3)) + 
  geom_point(size=4)+
  geom_text(data=df[3:4,],aes(x=var1,y=var2,label=var4), color='black')
```

To remove the circles for the 3rd and 4th row change the first row to this:

```
ggplot(data = df[-c(3:4),], aes(x=var1, y=var2, shape = var3, color = var3))
```

Is this ok?

Comment: thank you!...I would need to keep the points though so I will add 0.3 at x